# Como fazer a declaração explícita de tipo de variável em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem, php-7, declaração-de-variável

Fazendo um curso na internet, eu vi o instrutor dizendo que a partir do PHP 4 (ele usava o 3, então não testou) era possível fazer a declaração explícita de tipo em atributos de objetos da seguinte forma: `[escopo] $var:[tipo]`.

Exemplos:

```
class ClassePrincipal{
    // como eu quero realizar as conversões
    private $attr:ClasseSecundaria;
    public  $attr:Carbon;

    // como eu faço atualmente para manter uma tipagem forte
    public function exemplo(Obj1 $o1, string $s, int $i):bool{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Mas eu não encontro nada sobre o assunto, nem consigo realizar tais definições. Sei que dá pra fazer sem, mas gosto de trabalhar com tipagem forte em outras linguagens, e essa funcionalidade me chamou a atenção. Há uma forma de realizá-las, da mesma forma que se faz com as funções? Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Então use outra linguagem, a do PHP é gambiarra, não é o que está acostumado.

Comment: 1) Se está acostumado com isso em outras linguagens, por que mudar para o PHP? PHP não foi feito para ter tipagem forte. No geral, fazer isso traz mais problemas que soluções. 2) Se o curso que está fazendo usava PHP 3, corre! Já estamos na versão 7.3 da linguagem.

Comment: Se quiser dar uma olhada https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2, mas é gambiarra mesmo, não aceita void e as classes não implementam um mecanismo de conferência de tipos o que permite aplicar um valor inválido a uma propriedade sem que haja uma emissão de erro.

Comment: Augusto, pesquisei sobre elas e tentei aplicar, mas gera o seguinte erro: ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /Users/user/Projetos/test/Classe.php on line 3```, sabe se estou fazendo algo de errado? Obrigado (código abaixo).

Comment: ```<?php
  class ClasseTipada{
    public int $var1;
  }
?>```

Comment: ```<?php
  require_once 'ClasseTipada.php';
  $classe = new ClasseTipada();
    $classe->var1 = 2;
    $classe->var1 = 'soap';
?>```

Comment: Declare as propriedades sem o tipo, pois propriedades "tipadas"(ente aspas pois é uma tipagem fake) só são suportadas na versão 7.4 da linguagem.